# Changing colour of entire div not just the element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the 2nd element have a grey background but when i add the style to the div it only applies the background colour to the small span element. 
[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid row">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 small-margin-top" style="background-color: #e4e4e4">
    <p><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 26px;"></i> <strong>The Architect:</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-lg-9 small-margin-top" style="background-color: #e4e4e4">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner states in an answer (actually a comment) that he applied the CSS to wrong element making the question of no value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the background color to the row, not the columns. The column heights are only as tall as the content inside, that's why the first column is short.

Answer (score 3):

I was applying the style to the wrong div. It should applied to the "container-fluid row" div.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to have the whole element coloured grey. Why don't you apply the background-color to the row element?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid row">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 small-margin-top" style="background-color: #e4e4e4">
    <p><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 26px;"></i> <strong>Not how you want it.</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-lg-9 small-margin-top" style="background-color: #e4e4e4">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
</div>
<div>  t  </div>
<div class="container-fluid row" style="background-color: #e4e4e4">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 small-margin-top" >
    <p><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 26px;"></i> <strong>How you want it.</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-lg-9 small-margin-top">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the entire row's background color:

```
<div class="container-fluid row" style="background-color:#e4e4e4">
     .....
```